# Hash Calculation of a single file within disk image

Tags: hash, diskimage

I have got an assignment to calculate hash of a file from its disk image and then match it with simple pdf version hash. I have calculated starting and ending addresses of file from data section of `FAT32` following `FAT` table linked list implementation. Now is there any utility or software available to which I input disk image file and starting and ending addresses and it outputs hash value of specified data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hex Editor`'s `select block` option worked for me.